# Excel formula to remove space between words in a cell

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I've a huge data in excel file.

For eg: say i've a word like paul son,i've to make it as paulson.

input:`paul son`
output:`paulson`.

In some cells ,i've data like `mic-li`,when this type of words come,it should not replace any thing,it should only remove spaces in between words.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Suppose the data is in the B column, write in the C column the formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B1," ","")
```

Copy&Paste the formula in the whole C column.

**edit**: using commas or semicolons as parameters separator depends on your regional settings (I have to use the semicolons). This is weird I think. Thanks to @tocallaghan and @pablete for pointing this out.

Comment: as @Richard's answer, use comma's not semi-colons

Comment: @tocallaghan it depends on your regional configuration (I mean the comma vs semi-colons)

Answer (score 37):

It is `SUBSTITUTE(B1," ","")`, not `REPLACE(xx;xx;xx)`.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer, so it should be posted as a comment to the answer it concerns (when you have the rep to do so...)

Answer (score 6):

Steps (1) Just Select your range, rows or column or array , 
(2) Press ctrl+H , (3 a) then in the find type a space
(3 b) in the replace do not enter anything, 
(4)then just click on replace all.....
you are done.

Comment: For an excel illiterate like me, this was way too easier.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add on to vulkanino's answer... now 10 years later ha. This is what I was looking for maybe someone else is too. You can also build on multiple =SUBSTITUTE() functions.

Here is what I used to format a list of names for Active Directory accounts. B2 is where the name would go. I wanted to change the space between the First name and last to a period and omit any hyphens from names.

=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2, " ", "."), "-", "")

For example the line above would look like this:

First Last-Name => First.LastName

, "-", "")
This part removes the hyphen.

(B2, " ", ".")
This part selects the cell to modify and changes empty space to a period.

=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(...)...)
I used two substitute functions one inside the other.