# Trim not removing white spaces?

Tags: string, excel, hex

I have a field with hex a decimal values that look like FF FE, I need to remove the white space so the results are FFFE but trim is not working for me! Is there another function I can use?

Comment: `TRIM` removes only leading and trailing spaces. `Is there another function I can use` - yes, `=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")`

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190764/excel-formula-to-remove-space-between-words-in-a-cell

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578397/how-to-remove-leading-or-trailing-spaces-in-an-entire-column-of-excel-worksheet/9582919#9582919. Often the issue is CHAR(160)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trim only removes whitespace at the beginning and end. Use substitute instead.

```
=SUBSTITUTE({cell ref}," ","")
```

should do the trick